# How to connect 2 external monitors to MacBook Pro 2015

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, hdmi

I've an external monitor connected through HDMI and thinking about getting another external monitor for my MacBook Pro 2015.

How can I connect a second external display to my MacBook Pro?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53759/how-many-external-displays-can-i-power-with-the-15-retina-macbook-pro

Comment: Do you have the 13" or the 15"?

Answer (score 5):

With an MacBook Pro Early 2015 you can connect two display using Thunderbolt 2

> 2x up to 3840x2160 on external displays via Thunderbolt 2

or one display using Thunderbolt 2 and a second one using HDMI

> 1x single display up to 3840x2160 via Thunderbolt 2
>
> 1x single 1080p
>   display at up to 60 Hz, 3840x2160 at 30 Hz, or 4096x2160 at 24 Hz via
>   HDMI

So in your case you need a Mini DisplayPort to HDMI adapter for a second HDMI display. If you want to use display with a higher resolution you need to get another adapter (DVI, DisplayPort, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a MiniDisplay Port Cable for the second Monitor.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best.  Answers should be self-contained so explain why you think the answer you provided will solve the problem or is better than others out there.  Providing links as supporting information can also help the OP, and others, find additional info for themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review